# What is the best way to replace a JPanel with another one, inside a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I always wonder what is the best way to change the panels of my jframe, I would like to know of all the ways there are or which are the best depending on the case.

Comment: [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: "*all the ways there are*" -> StackOverflowException - there are (nearly?) infinite ways to do that - do never underestimated the creativity of developers  ||  "*best*" is very subjective, depends on the whole environment and even preferences

Answer (score -1):

You could do this, it is a veery clear approach in case your JFrame contains only 1 JPanel:

```
public void changePanelOfFrame(JFrame frame, JPanel newPanel) {
   frame.removeAll();
   frame.add(newPanel);
   frame.revalidate();
   frame.repaint();
}
```

If you are using e.g. BorderLayout with many objects in your jframe, you can replace a single JPanel too:

```
public void changePanelOfFrame(JFrame frame, JPanel panelToRemove, JPanel newPanel, Borderlayout position) {
   frame.remove(panelToRemove);
   frame.add(newPanel, position);
   frame.revalidate();
   frame.repaint();
}
```

Comment: As far as *"the best way"* goes, this .. isn't. The best way has been provided in the 1st comment under the question.

Comment: I don't see why there is a dislike. This solution works perfectly and there is no  need to use a special layout manager. To that, "the best way" is the one way, that works best in your given circumstances. But ok. To that, what if he uses many JPanels in his JFrame and only want to exchange the one, that is positioned at borderlayout.east? With this solution, this works easyly - with a one liner...